# python tkinter for loop used and image not loading

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

My image is not loading. I have no idea. Here is part of my code. The size of my image are small in height and width. Also only the last image shows for some reason:

```
lenlist1 = len(list1)
""" Displays text and photo """
for i in range(lenlist1):
    name = list1[i]
    Pic = Piclist[i]

    height = i * 400

    canvas.create_text(1,height,text=name,anchor=tkinter.NW)
    pic = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = Pic)
    root.pic = pic

    height2 = (i*400) + 20
    canvas.create_image(1,height2,image=pic, anchor = tkinter.NW)




frame.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time through that loop, the variable `pic` is assigned a new `tkinter.PhotoImage` object. If the previous object that was attached to that name has no other references to it, it is garbage-collected. As stated [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm):

> You must keep a reference to the image object in your Python program, either by storing it in a global variable, or by attaching it to another object.
>
> When a PhotoImage object is garbage-collected by Python (e.g. when you return from a function which stored an image in a local variable), the image is cleared even if it’s being displayed by a Tkinter widget.
>
> To avoid this, the program must keep an extra reference to the image object.

For example, you could append each `pic` to a list so that each image always has a reference to it.

Comment: how do you add a reference

Comment: @TayyabBaig - "you could append each `pic` to a list so that each image always has a reference to it"